# php autologout when browser closed

Tags: php, session

`session_set_cookie_params(0);` is not working .if browser is closed ,site should  be logout automaticaly. Please help me.

```
<?php
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
    session_start();
    include('connection.php');

    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    session_destroy();

    header('location:index.php');
?>
```

Comment: There is no real way to see when the browser is closed with PHP. You could use AJAX I suppose, but this assumes your users' browsers supports Javascript and they have it enabled.

Comment: Thanks for reply.tell me another way with ajax or javascript

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['email']` set in the first place? Sessions will automatically be destroyed when your Browser is closed, therefore if you are using a `$_SESSION` to stay logged in your user will be logged out automatically. Cookies stay in your Browser, until they expire.

Comment: sory i am new in php.i am not understand

Comment: You cannot `unset()` a `$_SESSION` that is not set in the first place. You set a session like: `session_start(); $_SESSION['email'] = 'whatever'`. Now `$_SESSION['email']` is set, and equals the String `'whatever'`. Once a user logs in you usually set a `$_SESSION` to make sure you can`t see pages otherwise. `$_SESSION`s won't make your site secure though. You should also use SSL, and other techniques to make sure someone can't just sniff a `$_SESSION`. I do a series of unique database queries and use SSL, myself, when needed.

Comment: Even if you use `$_COOKIE`s, if the user closes the Browser they are not connected to your site. Cookies are just tested against when visiting your site, if your site contains code that looks at `$_COOKIE`s. This is only a security risk if someone has access to the users Browser, which could automatically log a user back in if code is present to do so. It's not as if your user still has a connection to your site, if their Browser is not opened.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using javascript, all you have to do is to delete a cookie named " PHPSESSID " which allows the server to know what is the session id of the client,

```
function removeCookie(cookieName)
{
    cookieValue = "";
    cookieLifetime = -1;
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(cookieLifetime*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+JSON.stringify(cookieValue)+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

This is the function that deletes the cookie, all you have to do is to call the function when the user closes the browser

```
window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode()
{
  removeCookie("PHPSESSID");
}
```